# How to merge two ajax requests into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'm editing the form-edit-account.php template. This template contains a form that allows users to change account settings (name, surname, age etc ..). Originally the form had no ajax requests, so I added them to save data without page refresh. Everything works fine but I have some doubts about how I could refine the code.

When click on submit button of my form, in google console network tab I see that there are two requests, one belongs to Ajax Handling Error, while the other belongs to Ajax Save settings.

**Ajax Handling Error** allows me to view messages when form fields are not respected or success messages if all goes well.

**Ajax save settings**
actually saves the data without reloading the page.

What I would like to do is get a single request (saves settings and shows error messages). It's possible merge ajax hanling error code and ajax save settings code in a single request instead of two ?

**Js at the end of the form**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    //Ajax Handling Error
        var $form = $(this);
        $.post($form.attr('action'), 
        $form.serialize(), 
        function(data) {
          jQuery('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').html(data);
        }, 'json');

    //Ajax Save settings
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    });

    });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
function save_account_details() {
  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
    wc_add_notice("<b>Nome</b> è un campo obbligatorio", "error");
    $response = wc_print_notices(true);
  } else{
    wc_add_notice("Modifiche salvate con successo", "success");
    $response = wc_print_notices(true);
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here (to me). Your question is unclear.

Comment: I have clarified the question with further details, I apologize for the bad explanation, I hope this gets better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't know how right it can be, I'm just a fan and not a programmer. With this solution I only see a request in google console network card. Also everything works fine, the data is saved and the messages are ok. I post the solution below for anyone who is in the same situation as me.

**I just changed the script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    //Ajax Handling Error
        var $form = $(this);
        jQuery.post(
      $form.attr('action'), 
      $form.serialize(), 
      function(data) {
        jQuery('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').html(data);
          }, 'json'
    );

    //Ajax function
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
    });
    });
});
```